# run 100 selenium scripts gracefully at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I've searched and searched and searched but I cant seem to find a answer to my question.

I need to run up to 100 selenium scripts at the same time, where each script:

- has its own unique proxy, to avoid network traffic
- takes about 30 seconds to complete

All scripts need to finish within a 2 minute window, e.g. if I start running the scripts at 6:00 all scripts should be done by 6:02.

### I've looked at threading:

- The problem with this is, having 100 threads of chrome drivers hogs the CPU

### I've looked at multiprocessing

- 100 scripts would take to long with multiprocessing

### I've looked at concurrent features:

- 100 scripts also would take to long with concurrent features

Isn't there a way to gracefully run 100 selenium scripts at the same time, or at least run them within a 2 minute window.

### Here's what a sample script would look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def run():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless', )
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    self.browser.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')

    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchInput"))).send_keys('Python', Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Moved To Next Section ')

    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Computing"))).click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Moved To Next Section ')

    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "People"))).click()
    time.sleep(3)

    print('Moved To Next Section ')
    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Roller coasters"))).click()
    time.sleep(3)

    print('Moved To Next Section ')
    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Vehicles"))).click()
    time.sleep(3)

    print('Moved To Next Section ')
    WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Weaponry"))).click()
    time.sleep(100)


run()
```

Comment: Not a solution for you but I'd look to move away from Selenium to something lighter-weight... HtmlUnit (more capable) | JSoup (less standards compliant but should work). I'd then fire off 10-20 of the scripts at a time and wait for asynchronous responses using `CompletableFuture` and repeat. You'd more than likely be done well within 2 minutes.

Comment: i've seen some mention of HtmlUnit, but can this work with python, and am I able to click buttons, send text to input boxes ect

Comment: You can extract response data and create new HTTP requests using RestTemplate or (less preferable, unless you absolutely need to) Apache httpClient, then process the responses using HtmlUnit. Thats how I'd do it to avoid the overhead of Chrome.